# How to display container inside two columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to display the content of these two `columns` only inside the `container` and the `columns` take the full width of the page like this image down bellow.

Is this possible by using `css grid`?

Thank you for your help and your support.

[image: Column]

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns--container">
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm new to grids, but this should work:

```css
.columns {
  height: 400px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.columns-container {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  display: inherit;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns-container">
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```